# Recent comments per tagged post?

Tags: comments, tags

Could you please help me with some code to get all recent comments for posts that are tagged with for example "XYZ"?

Thanks in advance, you guys are great!

Comment: This is quite unresearched on your side, but I'll post an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As [Konstantin Kovshenin](http://kovshenin.com/) pointed out in [this article](http://kovshenin.com/2009/recent-comments-by-category-slug/), you can get the comments for a specific Category like that:

```
<?php
$show_comments = 10;
$i = 0;
$comments = get_comments("number=50&status=approve");
foreach ($comments as $comment)
{
    $comm_post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
    if (!has_term( 'XYZ', $comm_post_id );)
        continue;
    $i++;

    // Output the comment, author and whatever you need
    // I'll just output the comment excerpt to keep my code simple
    ?><li><?php comment_excerpt(); ?></li><?php

    if ($i >= $real_comments) break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The given code doesn't work, I edited a bit, especially this line:
    if (has_term( "blogs", $comm_post_id ))

And it displays all comments, not just from 1 tag.